# Update Windows 8 broke my GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, windows-8, uefi

Any update W8 broke my GRUB.

Normally, the boot-repair all repaired, now can not cope.

Details: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7612713/

Can you advise something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information presented, I don't believe that Windows replaced or damaged GRUB; rather, I believe that Windows simply moved its own boot loader to the start of the boot list. The evidence is here, from the Boot Repair output:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0000,0003,0006,0002,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,96800,32000,1026f553-af9e-4aac-b975-418a07be36f0)File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BIOS(2,0,00)AMGOAMNO........o.S.T.5.0.0.D.M.0.0.2.-.1.B.D.1.4.2....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .2.S.G.A.J.N.C.M......AMBO
Boot0002  UEFI: Wbudowana EFI Shell     Vendor(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012,)AMBO
Boot0003* grub  HD(2,96800,32000,1026f553-af9e-4aac-b975-418a07be36f0)File(EFIgrubgrubx64.efi)
Boot0005* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,96800,32000,1026f553-af9e-4aac-b975-418a07be36f0)File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0006* ubuntu    HD(2,96800,32000,1026f553-af9e-4aac-b975-418a07be36f0)File(EFIUbuntugrubx64.efi)
```

Note in particular the `BootOrder` line, which specifies the order in which the EFI tries to run boot programs. The first entry in that line is `0005`, which refers to `Boot0005`, which is the Windows boot loader.

This problem is easily fixed within Windows by using the `bcdedit` command from an *Administrator* Command Prompt window:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} description "Ubuntu"
```

These commands set Ubuntu's version of Shim, which in turn launches GRUB, as the default boot program, and sets a name that appears in some EFIs' boot loaders. (If you've disabled Secure Boot, you can change `shimx64.efi` to `grubx64.efi`, and in fact you may need to do this if Shim is not installed.) This solution is much less radical than running Boot Repair or re-installing GRUB in some other way, and is therefore less likely to cause unintended problems.

Some EFIs let you change the boot order within their user interfaces, and you can do the same thing with the `efibootmgr` utility within Linux. I describe the `bcdedit` solution merely because I know you can boot to Windows now.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) And you're right, I can change the boot order in EFI settings. I didn't know that ;)

Answer (score 0):

**** just answered a very similar question, so ill just copy and paste my answer, hope it helps. good luck *****

windows will overwrite GRUB boot menu(which is the dual boot screen you are referring to) i believe reinstalling GRUB from online through windows will fix your problem. another fix would simply be to reinstall Ubuntu, which installs the GRUB boot menu again, where u can decide between windows and Ubuntu. it is possible to retain your previous Ubuntu files this way. i would first try installing GRUB boot menu and making sure it is installed on the root of the first partition.. not an expert sorry but i believe this will solve your problem. good luck

**** i know that GRUB must be installed and run on the partition used initially the boot process. Gparted is a great way to repair this problem, unfortunately its a linux program. i had trouble finding a solution using windows disk manager, and was unable to change the default boot order. id advise possibly trying to live boot into Ubuntu, if you still have the disk if not make one, and then use Gparted to reapply the boot order. just right click on the partition you are booting Ubuntu from and select "manage flags" then check "boot" then try restarting your pc and see if that helped.