# Windows update broke GRUB2 so bad even a live USB key cannot boot (September 2021)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

(and welcome to a new "let's hate on Microsoft" thread)

Asus laptop with a 500GB SSD drive, with a 150GB NTFS Windows partition and a 350GB Ubuntu 20.04 partition (almost sure it is ext4). Dual boot with GRUB/Ubuntu having priority over Windows. Important data on the Ubuntu partition, not on the Windows one.

After a 1-hour Windows update, without any incident (no power outage or anything), the computer boots into the GRUB command line ("grub>", not "grub rescue>"). More annoyingly, this also happens when a live USB key is plugged (18.04, tested fine on another laptop). When using "exit" on the prompt Windows boots properly.

That was the overview, now for the specifics. With the live USB key first a screen quickly appears that reads

```
Failed to open EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

then after a second the "grub>" prompt appears

On the "grub>" prompt, ls returns

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt6) (hd2,gpt5) (hd2,gpt4) (hd2,gpt3) (hd2,gpt2) (hd2,gpt1)
```

ls (proc) returns

```
Device proc: Filesystem type procfs - Sector size 512B - Total size 0KiB
```

The live USB is hd0, and as expected ls (hd0,1) returns

```
Partition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'Ubuntu 18_0', UUID 864E-2850 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 15150080KiB
```

I do not know what hd1 is ; the computer previously had a HDD that was replaced with the SSD a few years back, perhaps it's a trace of that. ls (hd1) returns

```
Device hd1: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 2048B - Total size 514KiB
```

hd2 is the real hard drive. ls (hd2) describes the device

```
Device hd2: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 488386584KiB
```

ls (hd2,xx) for xx= 6 to 1 describes the partitions

```
Partition hd2,6: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 14684736KiB - Total size 341580800KiB
Partition hd2,5: Filesystem type ntfs, UUID84127C1A127C1380 - Partition start at 146205696KiB - Total size 598016KiB
Partition hd2,4: Filesystem type ntfs, UUID22FE5C86FE5C53DF - Partition start at 661504KiB - Total size 145543516KiB
Partition hd2,3: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 645120KiB - Total size 16384KiB
Partition hd2,2: Filesystem type fat, UUID 0057-5017 - Partition start at 542720KiB - Total size 102400KiB
Partition hd2,1: Filesystem type ntfs, Label 'Rcupration' - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 541696KiB
```

hd2,6 seems to be the 350GB Ubuntu partition. As far as I can tell it should not say "No known filesystem detected", in another laptop the ext structure is detected correctly by the grub ls command.
hd2,4 seems to be the Windows partition.
hd2,1 has a weird name because accents in French don't display

When I try to boot from the linux partition using

```
set prefix=(hd2,gpt6)/boot/grub
set root=(hd2,gpt6)
insmod normal
normal
```

nothing happens (I suppose it is expected if it can't tell the filesystem). When I try booting the key, using

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
normal
```

I get the live USB prompt, but then when I go for "Try Ubuntu without installing", or any other option, I get

```
error: /casper/vmlinuz has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
 
Press any key to continue...
```

then back to the live key menu, stuck in a loop. This is slightly weird, because earlier it warned me that grubx64.efi was not found, and from what I gather ([Update Windows 8 broke my GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483531/update-windows-8-broke-my-grub)) the fact that it did not ask for shimx64.efi means that Secure Boot is disabled, but then what is this signature thing ? In any case, the lack of a proper boot on the live USB key prevents me from using common repair tools.

Now I can still type "exit" and then Windows boots normally. On Windows, I tried downloading Testdisk. Testdisk does detect the Linux partition properly, as follows :

```
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors        
                                                                                                              
 1 P Windows Recovery Env        2048    1085439    1083392 [Basic data partition]                                      
 2 P EFI System               1085440    1290239     204800 [EFI system partition]                                      
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker                                                                   
 3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]                              
 3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]                              
 4 P MS Data                  1323008  292410039  291087032 [Basic data partition]                                      
 5 P Windows Recovery Env   292411392  293607423    1196032                                                             
 6 P Linux filesys. data    293609472  976771071  683161600
```

However when I go into that partition (with Advanced Utils) and try to list the files, I get

```
Support for this filesystem wasn't enabled during compilation
```

Only Windows boots properly, so I do not have another version on hand to try to work on the ext4 partition. Also I just downloaded the .exe and did not compile it myself, as I am not experienced enough to do that.

Some threads over at the Testdisk forums hint that when a partition is listed twice as 3 above it means there is a problem.

So...

My main goal is to gain access to the files of the Ubuntu partition, although repairing everything as it was yesterday would be really nice. I see a few possible avenues :

- somehow make GRUB boot the Ubuntu partition, reading it as the ext4 it is
- make GRUB boot the live USB key properly (with that signature thing), then use recovery tools from there
- use Testdisk (on Windows) to repair the ext4 partition so that GRUB can see it properly, or another similar tool in Windows
- use any tool to read the Ubuntu partition as ext4, get the files out, and throw the computer out the window.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Either way, thanks for reading !

Comment: The live USB may have issues, try creating the live USB once again. Also, verify that your Ubuntu image has correct checksums.

Comment: Windows updates reset fast start up on. Check & turn if off if on. Windows also may have done an UEFI update which resets UEFI settings to defaults. Turning RAID/Intel RST on, fast boot on, and changing Windows to first in boot order. Major update to grub does same thing as it makes Ubuntu/grub as first in boot order. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I had missed an option in the BIOS, Secure Boot was enabled. I disabled it and then I could boot from the live USB key, although I still needed to use set root and set prefix in the "grub" command line prompt, as per above.

Comment: From the live key, the disk utility sees the Ubuntu hard drive partition as /dev/sda6, partition type as Linux File, but no filesystem. Gparted sees no filesystem on it either.  I am getting the sense that this partition has been somehow damaged and that this is primarily a disk issue now. Boot-info report is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sddqs4qgzg/

Answer (score 0):

An update ; judging from a hexadecimal reader, the Linux partition has been thoroughly mangled beyond any recovery, at the byte level. Very short strings of text than I know with certainty to be in multiple plain text files cannot be found anywhere on the disk. Recovery tools (Photorec and R-Linux) do not retrieve any file at all, no jpeg, no plain text, nothing. While it might be possible that this is a physical dysfunction, its timing and perimeter (just the Linux partition, and all of it, while the Windows partition is bootable and perfectly functional) point to faulty software from the Windows update. This hypothesis cannot be easily explored though, so I'm left with my questions, my trashed partition, and a strong warning against dual boot for the future (at least without an ironclad backup setup).